# Solving recurrence relation containing $x(s+1),x(s),x(s+\frac{1}{2})$

Tags: calculus, recurrence-relations, recursion

Assume we have

$$ \frac{x(s+1)+x(s)}{2} =\alpha\, x(s+\frac{1}{2})+\beta.$$

the general solution is:

- if $\alpha\neq1$ then $x(s)=c_1\, k_1^{2s}+c_2\,k_2^{2s}+c_3$  ,

where $k_1,k_2$ are the roots of the equation $$k^2-2\alpha k+1=0$$
and $c_1,c_2$ are arbitrary functions of period $\frac{1}{2},c_3=\beta/(1-\alpha)$.

- When $\alpha=1$ we get $x(s)=c_1 s^2+c_2s+c_3,$

where $c_1=4\beta;c_2$ and $c_3$ are arbitrary functions of period $\frac{1}{2}$.

I couldn't solve this recurrence relation by using the characteristic root technique. please help

Comment: For what values of $s$ is $x(s)$ defined: half integers? All real numbers?

Comment: half integers as you can see from solution, there are arbitrary functions of period 1/2.

Comment: Maybe integers.

Comment: Hint: define the function $y(t) = x(t/2)$. If you set $t = 2s$, you can see that $y$ is defined by the relation $$\frac{y(t + 2) + y(t)}{2} = \alpha y(t+1) + \beta.$$ Can you see how to use the characteristic root method?

Comment: The problem is that there is $\beta$ on the right.

Comment: The $\beta$ just makes the recurrence non-homogeneous. You just need to find one special solution to this recurrence, and then the other solutions are the sums of that special solution and a function $z(t)$, where $z$ satisfies the corresponding homogeneous recurrence $$\frac{z(t+2) + z(t)}{2} = \alpha z(t+1).$$ If you're looking for a possible special solution, you might like to try one of the form $y(t) = k_1 t^2 + k_2 t + k_3$. See what coefficients $k_1, k_2, k_3$ make this function satisfy the recurrence relation for $y$.